# How can i insert data in sql table with select statement and some additional columns

Tags: sql-server

```
insert into
   [Client].[generalcontact_info]([userid], [first_name], [last_name],
                                  [email], [mobile],
                                  [country], [state], [city], [address],
                                  [Case_id], [contact_type], [query]) 
   select 
       [userid], [first_name], [last_name],
       [email], [mobile],
       [country], [state], [city], [address] 
   from 
       [Admin].[basicinfo] 
   where 
       [userid] = 100003

,'4521r521','Inside','what is my password'
```

I am taking some value from select statement and rest id from my own code

is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course it's possible - the `SELECT` used to insert can have both columns as well as "constants" in its list of values:

```
insert into
   [Client].[generalcontact_info]([userid], [first_name], [last_name],
                                  [email], [mobile],
                                  [country], [state], [city], [address],
                                  [Case_id], [contact_type], [query]) 
   select 
       [userid], [first_name], [last_name],
       [email], [mobile],
       [country], [state], [city], [address],
       '4521r521', 'Inside', 'what is my password'
   from 
       [Admin].[basicinfo] 
   where 
       [userid] = 100003
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3)
select col1, 'static_value', col2
from table2
```

Don't put your values not coming from the select after the select. Mix it with the select.